# In vue 3 is possible inject html code with directives obtained from an ajax request and have it recognize them?

Tags: dynamic, vuejs3, rendering, element

I am currently working on a page that we are updating from jQuery to Vue 3.

The page comes from the server with content rendered in a specific container and makes Ajax requests on demand to display more content in the same container.

The current issue is that the content arriving through the Ajax request contains Vue 3 directives, which are not recognized because Vue 3 is already running.

I know that by modifying the server response and converting it into an array, I could manipulate that information with the v-for directive. However, this is not an option due to compatibility with active jQuery versions.

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="card">
        Info
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        Info
    </div>
    ...
</div>

<buttom @click="loadMoreInfo">Load more<button>
```

Sample Vue3 method:

```
....
loadMoreInfo() {
    axios_ajax.loadMoreContent({
        "page": this.currentPage.nextPage,
        "limit": this.currentPage.limit
    }).then((response => {
        const container = document.getElementById('container');
        $(container).append(response.params.body);
        this.currentPage.nextPage++;
        this.$nextTick().then(() => {
            this.fixImageRatio();
        });
    })).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
},
....
```

I used the function this.$forceUpdate() within this.$nextTick(), but in Vue 3, it seems that it's no longer available or doesn't work in the way I used it.

```
this.$nextTick().then(() => {this.fixImageRatio();});
```

What I hope for is to be able to inject the new elements and have Vue recognize them if possible.